# The type or namespace name 'DataVisualization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.UI' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#

I added  System.Web.DataVisualization in my references folder but when I try to use it in a view like this

```
 <img src="/Chart/CreateChart?chartType=@(System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Column)"
```

I get this error

> The type or namespace name 'DataVisualization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.UI' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

It is, however, recognizable in my controller.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the reference and re-add again.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the `System.Web.DataVisualization.dll` in the bin folder of my project and it did work.